Incoming calls not working in React Native VOIP app using @twilio/voice-react-native-sdk
I need guidance on how to receive incoming calls and make outgoing calls using Twilio and React Native. Could you provide more detailed steps or support on setting this up?
for your info I can provide you with my node Js backend code:
const express = require("express");
const twilio = require("twilio");
const cors = require("cors"); // Import cors
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const port = 3000; // You can change the port if necessary
const { VoiceResponse } = require("twilio").twiml;
// Twilio credentials
const accountSid = "Twilio Account SID"; // Twilio Account SID
const apiKey = "Twilio API Key SID"; // Twilio API Key SID
const apiSecret = "Twilio API Secret"; // Twilio API Secret
const outgoingApplicationSid = "TwiML App SID"; // TwiML App SID

const client = twilio(accountSid, "Auth token");
// Add CORS middleware
let corsOptions = {
  origin: true, // This allows all origins
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Route to generate Twilio token
const identity = "client:username"; // Change this to a unique identity

app.get("/token", (req, res) => {
  // Identity could be unique per user; for testing, use 'client:username'

  // Create a new Voice Grant
  const VoiceGrant = twilio.jwt.AccessToken.VoiceGrant;
  const voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant({
    outgoingApplicationSid: outgoingApplicationSid,
    incomingAllow: true, // Allow incoming calls
  });

  // Create a new Access Token
  const AccessToken = twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
  const token = new AccessToken(accountSid, apiKey, apiSecret, { identity });
  token.addGrant(voiceGrant);

  // Serialize the token to a JWT
  const accessToken = token.toJwt();
  res.json({ token: accessToken });
});

app.post("/voice", (req, res) => {
  const { To, From } = req.body;
  console.log("to,from", req.body);
  const response = new VoiceResponse();

  const dial = response.dial({ callerId: From });
  dial.number(To);

  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  res.send(response.toString());
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

And below you can also see my Front-end react-native code also:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { Voice } from '@twilio/voice-react-native-sdk';
import axios from 'axios';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
// @ts-ignore

function App() {
  const [screenName, setScreenName] = useState('');
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [voiceInstance, setVoiceInstance] = useState<any>(null);
  const [toNumber, setToNumber] = useState('+919405237197');
  const [fromNumber, setFromNumber] = useState('+447446527790');
  const [baseUrl, setBaseUrl] = useState(
    'https://d660-103-190-12-135.ngrok-free.app',
  );

  const handleToken = async () => {
    const response: any = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/token`);
    console.log('response?.data?.token', response?.data?.token);
    setToken(response?.data?.token);
  };

  async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    requestUserPermission();
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleToken();
  }, []);
  // Handle incoming calls
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      const instance = new Voice();

      // Allow incoming calls
      instance.register(token);

      // Handle incoming calls
      instance.on(Voice.Event.CallInvite, (callInvite: any) => {
        console.log('Incoming call invite received:', callInvite);
        if (callInvite) {
          callInvite.accept(); // Accept the incoming call
          console.log('Call accepted');
        } else {
          console.error('No callInvite received');
        }
      });

      instance.on(Voice.Event.Registered, () => {
        console.log('Device registered successfully for incoming calls.');
      });
      instance.on(Voice.Event.Error, error => {
        console.error('Error during call event:', error);
      });

      setVoiceInstance(instance);

      // return () => {
      //   instance
      //     .unregister(token)
      //     .then(() => {
      //       console.log('Device unregistered successfully.');
      //     })
      //     .catch(error => {
      //       console.error('Error unregistering device:', error);
      //     });
      // };
    }
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          backgroundColor: 'black',
          height: '100%',
          padding: 10,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            margin: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 10,
            width: 200,
            color: 'black'
          }}
          onChangeText={setToNumber}
          value={toNumber}
          placeholder="To"
          placeholderTextColor='black'
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            margin: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 10,
            width: 200,
            color: 'black'
          }}
          onChangeText={setFromNumber}
          value={fromNumber}
          placeholder="From"
          placeholderTextColor='black'
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={async () => {
            await voiceInstance.connect(token, {
              params: {
                To: toNumber,
                From: fromNumber,
              },
            }).then((res: any) => { console.log("Request Successfull" + JSON.stringify(res)) }).catch((err: any) => {
              console.log(err)
            })
          }}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
            width: 100,
            margin: 10,
          }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 700, textAlign: 'center' }}>
            Call
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
export default App;

The above code is my react-native code when I try to make an outbound call from my app using the Twilio number to the verified number given in the code:
The response I am getting on my server console  is also given below:
to,from {
  ApplicationSid: 'AP6ffd09853cf39dbe857421f07b32da49',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  Called: '',
  Caller: 'client:client:username',
  CallStatus: 'ringing',
  From: '+447446527790',
  To: '+919405237197',
  CallSid: 'CA7a376ab036bae5e8ee9b66b2bc7a8aa6',
  Direction: 'inbound',
  AccountSid: 'AC5ce507f0fe2c96ea680825ff9023698a'
}

As we can see here we are making an outbound call but getting Direction as 'inbound' but I can still get a call on this number from my Twilio number so can you please help me understand this? Also, what do I do to make an incoming call successful here and show it in the react-native app that I am receiving a call and can receive it? I am also adding call logs of my Twilio call logs so that you can see I can make calls here but please help make an app that can receive incoming calls also.
Here is my technology stack given here:
"@twilio/voice-react-native-sdk": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.75.2",
    "platform": "android"



